# State not getting changed and rendered on screen

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the state of the "currNum" in the PressButton class component and render it in the Header class component but i don't see this working. here is the code... I have  define the state in the App class and trying to change it in the PressButton class is this allowed and if not how do I achieve this.

```
import React from 'react';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={
     score: 0,
     prevNum: 1,
     currNum: 0
   }
  };
  render()
  {
    return(
      <div>

        <PressButtons currNum={this.state.currNum} prevNum={this.state.prevNum} prevScore={this.state.score}/>
        <Header score={this.state.score} currNum={this.state.currNum}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
  class Header extends React.Component {
    render(){
      console.log('curnum in headert is '+this.props.currNum);
      return(
        <div>
        <h1>Current Number:{this.props.currNum}</h1>
        <h1>Current score: {this.props.score}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }


  class PressButtons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.clickOne = this.clickOne.bind(this);
    }
    clickOne(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      const val = 1;
      const prev = this.props.prevNum;
      var prevScore= this.props.prevScore;
      var currNum=this.props.currNum;

      console.log(prev);
      console.log(prevScore);
      if(val === prev)
      {
        prevScore+=1;
      }
      this.setState(()=>{
        return {
          score: prevScore ,
          currNum: 1,
          prevNum: 1
        };
      });
       console.log('curnum is '+currNum);
    }
    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><button onClick={this.clickOne}>One</button></td>
              <td><button>Two</button></td>
              <td><button>Three</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button>Four</button></td>
              <td><button>Five</button></td>
              <td><button>Six</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button>Seven</button></td>
              <td><button>Eight</button></td>
              <td><button>Nine</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: Can we change the state in the child component if we have our state defined in parent component without using the handler function.

Answer (score 0):

You used `setState()` for the ***local*** `PressButtons`, so when `clickOne()` is called, the ***local*** `PressButtons` state change, but the `App` state doesn't change.

So, to change the App state, you should [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). It means to move the `clickOne()` to `App` class. So when `clickOne()` is called, the `App` state will be changed, and the `Header` props also changed

Answer (score 0):

In React, data flows unidirectional, which means everything tends to flow from parent to child, top to bottom, and before to after (with respect to time).

The way we typically handle situations like this is to supply everything to the children components and maintain state in the component that controls behavior, which is typically the parent.

The part you are interested in is that to provide data changes back to the parent, you can and should use callbacks. When you use callbacks, the child can use callback closure to observe anything in the parent's scope needed at the time.

The benefit is this frees the child component from caring about details that are outside its scope of responsibility.

I will draw you a simple example that shows the pattern, and you can apply it to your problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { id: 1, content: 'hello' },
        { id: 2, content: 'world' },
      ],
    }
  }

  handleFancyClick = (data) => {
    console.log('CURRENT STATE', this.state.items)
    console.log('DATA FROM CHILD', data)

    const newItems = [...this.state.items, data]
    console.log('NEW STATE', newItems)

    this.setState({
      items: newItems
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Happy Day! We got some YOLO data:</h1>
        <hr />
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.content}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Child
          onFancyClick={this.handleFancyClick}
          specialData={this.state.items}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Child = (props) => {
  const currentListLength = props.specialData.length
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => props.onFancyClick({ id: (currentListLength + 1), content: 'that\'s rad' })}
      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
    >
      Hey I'm a stateless child, woot (also: {currentListLength})
    </button>
  )
}

export default Parent
```

There are a couple important things to notice here:

1. State is managed in the parent `this.state.items`.
2. The parent uses a Class Method called `handleFancyClick` to update its state.
3. The parent defines the prop key that the child will use, in this case called `onFancyClick`. It is a callback. You can see that it's telling the child "When you call `props.onFancyClick()`, I am going to execute my `this.handleFancyClick()` using whatever data you pass me.
4. Whenever the child is ready to, it executes `props.onFancyClick()` which triggers the callback.
5. Also notice that inside `handleFancyClick`, we replaced `this.state.items` immutably. This is good practice to always replace Objects or Arrays when you update them, because doing so breaks the reference in memory and will avoid problems with state. Remember, React is unidirectional, so things happen over time, and to avoid something being incorrect at a point in time, we follow strict immutable philosophy.

Hopefully that helps. I wrote a large article about immutable functional programming that you can read if you want to understand more about references and garbage collection in JavaScript: https://medium.com/@agm1984/an-overview-of-functional-programming-in-javascript-and-react-part-one-10d75b509e9e

Study the code I showed here. It was hard for me to understand when I first learned it because it's jumping dimensions from parent to child and back to parent. I recommend writing it out maybe a couple times until you can totally understand the pattern. You will use it a lot.